# How to remove recaptcha for dev purposes?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have inherited some php code for a website that was being developed but the person has left and the code is rather all over the place, what i need is to remove all traces of recaptcha code, so that i can just test and dev the page without the annoying captcha everytime, the page is for internal use currently and not online, i have tried removing this code myself but nothing seems to work.

I have tried using the code as is but recaptcha always comes up with internal error occured, as such the page useless currently.

Pastebin of code: `http://pastebin.com/udpypCbd`

Please guide me.

Comment: Comment out the areas around the `recaptcha_*` stuff and comment out the `if (!$resp->is_valid)...` statement.

Comment: Tried the commenting out, however just give me a blank page

Comment: Sounds like error messages are off - if they are, you need to switch that back on. Did you look at the html source (the rendered PHP) of the "blank" page?

Comment: So i used <?php error_reporting(-1); ?> for the page in question, but still loads up a blank page, did a view source on the blank page, just opens up a new page that is also blank

Comment: cant edit my comment so sorry about that but, check thed php.ini file and error reporting is on. error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT